Quenching reagents for specific reaction
A reaction general procedure is given as follows:

A mixture of 2-fluoro-5-iodo pyridine $(\pu{1.0 mmol})$, methyl
acetoacetate $(\pu{3.0 mmol})$, $\ce{CuI}$ $(\pu{10 mol\%})$,  $\ce{K3PO4}$ $(\pu{3.0 mmol})$, and alcohol additive $(\pu{3.0 mmol})$ in DMSO $(\pu{4 mL})$ was stirred in  $\ce{N2}$ at $\pu{80 ^\circ C}$. After completion of the reaction, the mixture was quenched with diluted hydrochloride $(\pu{2 mL}, \ 2M)$, and the solution was extracted with ethyl acetate $(3 \times \pu{5 mL})$.

The product is methyl 2-(6-fluoro-3-pyridyl)acetate.

Since the product contains a pyridine ring, can I quench it with hydrochloride $(\pu{2 mL}, \ 2M)$?
What is the best reagent for quenching?
If I start with $\pu{200 mg}$ of 2-fluoro-5-iodo pyridine, how much quenching reagent do I need?
How can I remove the copper salt?


MW of 5-fluoro-2-iodopyridine is 223 so 1 mmol is 223 mg. Starting with 200mg is very close to the described procedure so no need to adjust the amount of HCl quench. Due to the presence of the 6-F the pyridine is less basic.

“ stirred in N2 at 80 ∘C”?

Yes, I purged the flask with N2 and set the temperature to 80 °C.

@Karsten Well, $\pu{4 mL}$ of DMSO are present as a solvent in addition to the liquid methyl acetoacetate. But since nitrogen gas doesn't form a blanket to cover a reaction mixture which argon would provide, the description «in an atmosphere of nitrogen» or "in N2 atmosphere" is not wrong (though it sounds a bit like cell culture incubators in biochemistry) ...

@Ella Does the reference/paper not include more detailed SI?  Why can't a filtration across an already EtOAc wetted plug of celite be an option (I infer from Pd coupling reactions), e.g. in a bigger Pasteur pipette, or made of a test tube to remove the CuI for good?  See e.g., the blog post of the Baran lab; at first it needs some training by a colleague, but then works well enough.
